# Extract attribute value from XML in JRuby

Tags: ruby, xml, jruby

I need to extract the value of an attribute. From the xml below I need to extract the value '9'.

```
xmlDoc = <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><config version='9'><roaming>false</roaming></config>
```

I am using this code but only getting the whole xml instead of value.

```
XPath.match(xmlDoc, "/config[@version]")
```

Comment: Which XPath class is this? I can not find a gem to use without an error from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
Hash.from_xml(xmlDoc)['config']['version']
```

Comment: Thanks Sajin but got this error.  NoMethodError: undefined method `from_xml' for Hash:Class

Comment: @Zaf maybe you have to require activesupport

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Nokogiri, though it might be overkill for a simple config file.

```
require 'nokogiri'
Nokogiri::XML(xmlDoc).xpath('/config/@version').text
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help. I tried nokogiri and getting this error, ArgumentError: must be kind_of String or respond to :to_io, :read, or :string

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Sajin and Mark for your support on this. I got it working with this.

```
XPath.first(xmlDoc, "/config/@version]").value
```

The answer returned as 9